# How to put another line of string (still in one phrase) in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, string, query-string, concatenation

I want to put or cut my string into couple of lines. How could I do that?
this is the line of codes I want to cut (but they are still in string).

```
sql = "INSERT INTO tblClientInfo (genClientID, fullName, address, comaker, colateral, atmPIN, principal, "
                & "interest, principalInWords, terms, interestPerMonth, principalperMonth, totalPayment, interestPercentage, "
                & " interestBal, principalBal, theDate, totalBal)"
```

This code returns an error. What is the proper way of concatenation or cutting a long string?

Comment: The tern you're after is "line continuation character".  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711641(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to indicate that the line continues to the next line by suffixing each line to be continued with a space followed by an underscore, as follows:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO tblClientInfo (genClientID, fullName, address, comaker, colateral, atmPIN, principal, " _
  & "interest, principalInWords, terms, interestPerMonth, principalperMonth, totalPayment, interestPercentage, " _
  & " interestBal, principalBal, theDate, totalBal)"
```

Additional reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711641%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I like `String.Concat()` because you don't need line-continuation underscores and you don't need ampersands. Just looks cleaner.

```vb
sql = String.Concat( 
    "INSERT INTO tblClientInfo (genClientID, fullName, address, comaker, colateral, atmPIN, principal, ",
    "interest, principalInWords, terms, interestPerMonth, principalperMonth, totalPayment, interestPercentage, ",
    "interestBal, principalBal, theDate, totalBal)" )
```

Comment: it returns a syntax error... but I like the idea if it's working

Comment: @JayMarz Weird, it's working for me. As long as `sql` is defined.

Comment: I don't know too. Maybe there're something to import or what.